# parallel programing with openMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I just did an example project "Hello world" with openMP just to see how it works.

Here is the code:

```
    #include <omp.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
       #pragma omp parallel
       {
          cout <<"Hello World\n";
       }

          return 0;
     }
```

from what I understood it suppose to print "Hello world" multi-times (as the number of the processors, no?) I mean that if I have a dual core it suppose to print this line 2 times, am I right? 
anyway it prints just one time, and I wonder why? 
I'm using Visual Studio 10 and running the code from there..

Comment: Have you enabled OMP in your VS project?

Comment: OpenMP relies on compiler support to be available, it's not a library or some piece of source code from third parties, you should document yourself about how to do OpenMP programming with your compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable Open MP support in your Visual Studio (Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Open MP Support -> Yes).